# Facebook 'Where You're Logged In' IP does not match actual IP

Tags: ip, facebook

In Facebook, go to "Settings" > "Security and login" > "Where You're Logged In", and hover the mouse over the characters which describe your location. You should see your IP.

But when I do it, its not matching my actual IP (now, because apparently it always matched before).

I'm not using a VPN or a proxy, and I'm not accessing Facebook from any other devices. What could be happening?

Comment: How did you check your actual IP? Maybe that service isn't working properly?

Comment: @Anders: It should only show the IP of the session you are currently using to check the IP.

Comment: As to how I'm checking my IP, its 

Using  # curl -s checkip.dyndns.org | sed -e 's/.*Current IP Address: //' -e 's/<.*$//' 

And 'my ip' in google. I guess It can't go wrong,,

Comment: make sure your not comparing your *local* ip with Facebook instead of you actual remote ip

Comment: Have you done a lookup on the IP address to see which network it belongs to? That might give you additional clues.

Comment: Anders added "I'm not using a VPN or a proxy, and I'm not accessing Facebook from any other devices." to the question right after I started looking for VPNs, and I don't know him. Thats weird.

Comment: I'm having the same issue as @galmeida . It appears to be a Facebook bug. Facebook reports that my current session is in Dorr, MI, United States. When I hover over Door, MI, Facebook report my IP as 2602:306:bd2b:b52f:48f1:348e:e85b:a172 which is my correct IP address, but every IP location service, like www.iplocation.net , reports that IP as from Windsor, CA. Windsor is correct. That is where my ISP is based. Neither me or my computers or VPN ever been in Michigan.

Answer (score 1):

There are quite a few apps that interface with FB. In addition to flat out showing the wrong location for an IP, I suspect FB gets confused and maybe shows your location as the most frequently logged in location rather than most recent or currently active login. I have a calendar app that syncs my FB events to my google calendar on the hour. Logging out of FB, clearing my web cache, and logging back in doesn't fix the location issue.

After "ending all activity" on the FB Security and Login settings, which forced my calendar app and all the others (like Bumble) to disconnect, then logging back in, my location corrected. It also corrected to my actual location, rather than just my ISP's central location.

This is hardly a fix or an answer to the problem, but it's a way to get your location corrected if you're willing to give up the utility of FB interfacing apps.